# Same str symbol indicating both sep (delimiter) and decimal. read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I would be glad if you could lend me a hand to solve this problem!
I have a file .dat that I want to try to read it as a csv. I have the datas as I write here:

```
"Numbers","0,034","734"
"Number","10,45","1,2"
```

I want it as a dataframe. How do yo specify which comas are delimiters and which ones are decimals? Or asked other way, are we able to point `" "` as the container of the elements of the dataframe?

Thank you very much forever!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `pandas.read_csv` in Jupyter, it works fine as it is now.  It just interprets the decimal values as strings.

Note that, in a CSV, everything is in columns, so you may have to transpose your data frame using `df.T`.  Also, to convert your decimals into numeric decimals in Python., you'll need to do the following:

`df.applymap(lambda x: float(x.replace(',','.'))`

Comment: Thank you! you're right. Then my problem is about the dimension of my dataframe... I thought I was having error because of what I asked, however that works as you are saying. I didn't try it before.